# How to I convert month name to number in BSD date?

Tags: osx, date, bsd

I have found solutions for GNU `date`, but not for BSD `date`. I would rather not make an `if`, etc. before I know if there's a built in way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert `October` to `10`, for example (I have Swedish locale)

```
date -jf %B Oktober '+%m'
```